# Using "first" in dplyr to select groups's first value that is not NA

Tags: r, dplyr

My df "temp" looks like the first four columns of the following:

```
ID OBS NUMER DENOM   RATIO
1  1   26    NA      1.5
1  2   10    NA      0,5556
1  3   18    18      1
1  4   51    26.333  1,461
2  1   17    NA      0,2
```

I am trying to add the fifth column by dividing the group's values for the column NUMER by the group's first value of DENOM that is not NA. How do I do this?

```
temp %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(RATIO = NUMER/first(DENOM[!is.na(DENOM)]))
```

Running this command however, gives me the following error message:

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `RATIO` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 0.

I've also tried

```
temp %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(RATIO = NUMER/first(.$DENOM[!is.na(.$DENOM)]))
```

but in this case, it seems to divide by the the first value of the entire DENOM column, instead of the group's first value for that column. Please help! :(

Comment: Just remove the `.$` in `.$DENOM`.  You need `first(DENOM[!is.na(DENOM)])` as `.$` will extract the whole column disrupting the group by 'ID'

Comment: That's what I did in the first command, right? If I run that command, I get the error message "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column RATIO must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 0."

Comment: Based on your example, it is working fine for me.  May be you have groups where 'DENOM' is only `NA`. In that case, use a `if/else` condition i.e. `if(all(is.na(DENOM)) NA_real_ else `

Comment: The issue is that the second `ID` group has no non-na `DEMOM` values.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan. Even that works fine for me

Comment: I'm getting the same error. But the `if/else` option should fix it

Comment: @IceCreamToucan In the example above, the second group is only an extract of a much larger sample. I will verify akrun's solution.

Comment: @TimHaus If you can update the `dput` of the example that gives such a problem, it would be helpful

Comment: you can also use `first(na.omit(DENOM))`