# Using "first" in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe looks something like the first four columns of the following:

```
   ID             Obs    Seconds     Mean               Ratio
   <chr>        <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>             <dbl>
 1 1815522          1          1     NA                 1/10.6
 2 1815522          2         26     NA                 26/10.6       
 3 1815522          3          4.68  10.6               4.68/10.6
 4 1815522          4          0     10.2               0/10.6  
 5 1815522          5          1.5    2.06              1.5/10.6
 6 1815522          6          2.22   1.24              2.22/10.6
 7 1815676          1         12     NA                 12/9.67
 8 1815676          2          6     NA                 6/9.67    
 9 1815676          3         11      9.67              11/9.67 
10 1815676          4          1      6                 1/9.67 
11 1815676          5         30     14                 30/9.67 
12 1815676          6         29     20                 29/9.67
13 1815676          7         23     27.3               23/9.67
14 1815676          8         51     34.3               51/9.67
```

I am trying to add a fifth column "Ratio", containing the ratio of each row's value for Seconds, and the ID-group's first not-NA value of Mean. How do I do that?

I've tried several things:

```
temp %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Ratio = case_when(all(is.na(Mean)) ~ NA_real_, 
                                   !all(is.na(Mean)) ~ Seconds/(first(Mean[!is.na(Mean)]))))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Ratio` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 0
```

I also tried

```
temp %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Ratio = ifelse(!all(is.na(Mean)), Seconds/(first(Mean[!is.na(Mean)])), NA_real_))
```

But in this case, it will create a column that looks like this:

```
               Ratio
               <dbl>
 1            0.0947
 2            0.0947
 3            0.0947
 4            0.0947
 5            0.0947
 6            0.0947
 7            1.24  
 8            1.24  
 9            1.24  
10            1.24  
11            1.24  
12            1.24  
13            1.24  
14            1.24
```

I really don't know what else to try. Please help! :)

Comment: Can you show your desired output? Because it's not clear from the description.

Comment: The desired output is the column "Ratio" in the first table depicted (where of course I'd want the values of the fractions depicted. I included to make the column's definition more transparent)

Comment: I changed the wording a bit to make the desired column more clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "first" in dplyr to select groups's first value that is not NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348564/using-first-in-dplyr-to-select-groupss-first-value-that-is-not-na)

Answer (score 2):

An idea is to use `fill` with `.direction = 'up'` since you are interested in the `first` value, to fill your NAs and simply divide with the first value. No need for `case_when` to capture all NAs since it will by default give NA as an answer, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 fill(Mean, .direction = 'up') %>% 
 mutate(ratio = Seconds / first(Mean))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 14 x 5
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>         ID   Obs Seconds  Mean  ratio
>      <int> <int>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
>  1 1815522     1    1    10.6  0.0943
>  2 1815522     2   26    10.6  2.45  
>  3 1815522     3    4.68 10.6  0.442 
>  4 1815522     4    0    10.2  0     
>  5 1815522     5    1.5   2.06 0.142 
>  6 1815522     6    2.22  1.24 0.209 
>  7 1815676     1   12     9.67 1.24  
>  8 1815676     2    6     9.67 0.620 
>  9 1815676     3   11     9.67 1.14  
> 10 1815676     4    1     6    0.103 
> 11 1815676     5   30    14    3.10  
> 12 1815676     6   29    20    3.00  
> 13 1815676     7   23    27.3  2.38  
> 14 1815676     8   51    34.3  5.27
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

 df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    isNA = mean(is.na(Mean)),
    Ratio = if_else(isNA == 1, NA_real_, Seconds / first(Mean[!is.na(Mean)]))
  )
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have groups for which all values in Mean are NA, which is why I include the if-statement. combining your answer with the if-statement yields the command I tried (see above)